# Passing a stored instance of an object to another form

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, screenshot

I'm trying to get my screen shot image to be displayed in a picture box held on my Control panel form. But the image is not getting passed over.

I have been informed that the issue may be laying within the following lines of code:

```
      ScreenCapture capture = new ScreenCapture();
         capture.CaptureImage(showCursor, curSize, curPosition, startPoint, Point.Empty, bounds, _screenPath, fi);
```

As I'm creating a new screen capture, the data isn't getting passed over to the my picture box. When I run my program the errors originate with the following lines always returning null:

```
 Image img = (Image)bitmap;
 if (OnUpdateStatus == null) return;

 ProgressEventArgs args = new ProgressEventArgs(img);
 OnUpdateStatus(this, args);
```

Then in my control panel winform I'm trying to display the image as follows:

```
private ScreenCapture _screenCap;

public ControlPanel()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _screenCap = new ScreenCapture();
    _screenCap.OnUpdateStatus += _screen_CapOnUpdateStatus;

}



private void _screen_CapOnUpdateStatus(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
{

    imagePreview.Image = e.CapturedImage;
}
```

The advice I was given was as follows:

> You're looking at the value of OnUpdateStatus within the CaptureImage
>   method, right? So it matters which instead of ScreenCapture you call
>   the method on. I suspect you need to pass _screenCap to the
>   constructor of Form1 (which would need to store it in a field) so that
>   you could use the same instance when you call CaptureImage within
>   Form1

I have no idea how to implement the advice that was given to me. In my first two lines of code I simply tried to take away the creation of a new instance of my ScreenCapture class and write

```
  ScreenCapture.CaptureImage(showCursor, curSize, curPosition, startPoint, Point.Empty, bounds, _screenPath, fi);
```

But this generates the following error:

> Error 1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'DotFlickScreenCapture.ScreenCapture.CaptureImage(bool, System.Drawing.Size, System.Drawing.Point, System.Drawing.Point, System.Drawing.Point, System.Drawing.Rectangle, string, string)'

So to get rid of this error I turned the Method being called to a static class but this generated a whole host of different errors with my code trying to store the image taken:

```
     Image img = (Image)bitmap;
     if (OnUpdateStatus == null) return;

     ProgressEventArgs args = new ProgressEventArgs(img);
     OnUpdateStatus(this, args);
```

It claims that my OnUpdateStatus require an object reference and that using the THIS keyword where I have is not valid in a static field or environment.

Is anyone able to help with getting my image to be displayed in an image box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sincerely I could not understand your code. But I understood the advice was given to you. It says that pass the object of captured screen to the form's constructor:

Lets say you have a form name `form1`. Here is the constructor and little code you must have in the `form1` class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Image CapturedImage;

    public Form1(Image imgObj) //"you need to pass _screenCap to the constructor of Form1"
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CapturedImage = imgObj; //"which would need to store it in a field"
    }
}
```

The constructor is taking the captured image as an object(Image imgObj) and assign it to the field(Image CapturedImage;).

If you want to display it in the `picturebox`. Simply add this line in the constructor as well:

```
picturebox.Image = CapturedImage;
```

Now to call it from another form, do it like this:

Capture screen as you are doing (your first code is correct in which you create object of `ScreenCapture` class) and save it in an object:

```
Image CapturedImageObj = capture.CaptureImage(showCursor, curSize, curPosition, startPoint, Point.Empty, bounds, _screenPath, fi);
```

Now create instance of `form1` and pass captured image to the constructor of the form:

```
form1 ImageForm = new form1(CapturedImageObj);
```

and display it:

```
form1.Show();
```